# Plotedit state of a Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, figure

How can I extract the `plotedit` state of a Matlab figure inside a function? If I want to know the zoom state of the current figure, I can write:

```
zoomState =  get(zoom(gcf), 'Enable');
```

A similar syntax for `plotedit` does not work, since `plotedit(gcf)` toggles the `plotedit` state without returning anything. Without having a way to get `plotedit`'s current state, I have no clue how to temporarily put it to 'off' and restore its value once my function has finished. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received an answer from the MathWorks on this issue:

> here is an undocumented feature that you might want to use :
>
> ```
> ison = plotedit(gcf,'isactive')
> ```
>
> This will tell you if PLOTEDIT is active or not. However, since this
>   is undocumented it might change or not work in future releases.

I think that this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `open plotedit` at the command line, you will see that it is actually an m-file. When the state is toggled, it calls the undocumented function `activateuimode` to do the dirty work. Taking a wild guess, I typed `help getuimode` at the command line and got back the message

```
  This function is undocumented and will change in a future release
```

So the function exists. Presumably, calling it with the same input arguments as `activateuimode` in `plotedit` will do what you want. That is,

```
getuimode(myFigHandle, 'Standard.EditPlot')
```

On my system, it returns `[]` if not in edit mode, and an instance of `uitools.uimode` if it is.

Note, however, that this approach may be a bit dodgy - as the help says, it will probably change in a future release. If you open `getuimode`, you will see it has been the same since 2007, but as I understand it there has been a major overhaul of the UI system in R2013, so it may have changed in the most recent release (I'm running R2012a).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I tried   `getuimode(myFigHandle, 'Standard.EditPlot')`, but this gives me `uitools.uimode` regardless of the `plotedit` state.